# Mybatis PostgreSQL throws an error "column does not exist" for an column that exists and its values are auto generated

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-mapper, postgresql-13

Below is the create table statement which has successfully created the table in the PostgreSQL database.

```
CREATE TABLE
    SYNC_REPOSITORIES (
        REPOSITORY_ID BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
        REPOSITORY_NAME VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        REPOSITORY_KIND VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
        LOGIN_NAME VARCHAR(256),
        LOGIN_INFO VARCHAR(2000),
        CONSTRAINT REPO_NAME_U UNIQUE (REPOSITORY_NAME));
```

Mybatis mapper.xml
for insert

```xml
<insert id="insertRepository" parameterType="RepositoryDO" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id" keyColumn="REPOSITORY_ID">
    INSERT INTO SYNC_REPOSITORIES (
          REPOSITORY_NAME,
          REPOSITORY_KIND,
          LOGIN_NAME,
          LOGIN_INFO)
    VALUES (
          #{name},
          #{kind},
          #{loginName,jdbcType=VARCHAR},
          #{loginInfo,jdbcType=VARCHAR})
  </insert>
```

Since REPOSITORY_ID is auto generated value, I have not added it in the insert statement.
When this is executed via sqlSessionFactory , it returns an error saying

**The error occurred while setting parameters**

```
SQL: INSERT INTO SYNC_REPOSITORIES (     REPOSITORY_NAME,     REPOSITORY_KIND,     LOGIN_NAME,        LOGIN_INFO)     VALUES (     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?)
### Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "REPOSITORY_ID" does not exist
  Position: 194
; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "REPOSITORY_ID" does not exist
  Position: 194
```

The same mapper xml works for MSSQL and also ORACLE database. I am new to PostgreSQL.

Comment: Replace `keyColumn="REPOSITORY_ID"` to `keyColumn="repository_id"` and try.

Comment: Take a look at the table in `psql`. I'm betting the table name and column names are all lower case. If you don't double quote them when creating the table identifiers will be folded to lower case. Which as @AkhileshMishra said will cause this `keyColumn="REPOSITORY_ID"` to throw the error.  For more information in the Postgres docs see [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for pointing out the lower case thing. In both MSSQL and ORACLE the table names and columns are in uppercase. In Postgresql , tables and columns are in lowercase. Keeping the keyColumn="repository_id" in lower case in mapper.xml definitely worked for PostgreSql.  MSSQL also doesn't seem to have a problem, it is able to map to the uppercase column. Need to check if the lower case keyColumn="repository_id" works for Oracle too.

Comment: Please read the link I posted previously. The issue is that the SQL standard says unquoted names will  be folded to UPPER CASE. Postgres in a deviation from the standard folds to lower case. In either case quoting a name will preserve the case. Your problem is you mixed quoted and unquoted naming of things. That will be an issue in all databases if you are not careful and consistent.